# Smooth scrolling when a link is clicked on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a site and have anchor links at the top of the site. On a computer, when I press a link, it scrolls to the given section in a smooth manor, but on a phone it just jumps straight to the section. I originally used scroll-behavior: smooth, but implemented JavaScript code instead because I thought that may fix the problem; it didn't. Below I have attached my html code and JavaScript code I am currently using:

```
    <nav class="nav">
        <h6 id="site">website.net</h6>
        <ul class="nav__links">
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#about" class="link">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#experience" class="link">Link2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#skills" class="link">Link3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
              <a href="#projects" class="link">Link4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hidden--btn menu--btn">
          <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
/*scroll animation */
const scrollTo = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = e.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('link')) {
        const id = target.getAttribute('href').slice(1);
        document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    }

    if (target.classList.contains('hamburger--link')) {
        const id = target.getAttribute('href').slice(1);
        document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
        hamburgerBin.classList.toggle('hidden--two');
    }
}

nav.addEventListener('click', scrollTo);
```

Comment: So, any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I know its JavaScript I mentioned that in the question and language tags... No errors in the console, it works on computer not a phone.

Comment: Which browser version in which OS version of which phone - or did you try multiple